# Laravel 5.2 email verification error

Tags: laravel, email, verification

I followed the tutorial on [this site](https://blog.damirmiladinov.com/laravel/laravel-5.2-email-verification-with-activation-code.html#.V6C2OPkrK03) to help me build email verification for new users. 
I keep getting the error:

```
FatalErrorException in ActivationService.php line 66:
Call to a member function getActivation() on null
```

Here is the routes.php:

```
Route::auth();
Route::get('user/activation/{token}', 'Auth\AuthController@activateUser')->name('user.activate');
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
Route::get('auth/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
```

here is the .env file

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailgun.org
MAIL_FROM=*from address given by mailgun*
MAIL_NAME=CompanyName
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=*Mailgun username*
MAIL_PASSWORD=*Mailgun password*
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls

MAILGUN_DOMAIN=*mailgun domain*
MAILGUN_SECRET=*secret key*
```

Everything else has been done according to the code given on the tutorial. Please refer to the code [there](https://blog.damirmiladinov.com/laravel/laravel-5.2-email-verification-with-activation-code.html#.V6C2OPkrK03), as my code is the same for the classes.

Comment: When does this happen? When a new user registers or when a not activated user tries to login?

Comment: When a new user registers. It still makes an entry into the SQL database, despite throwing the error.

Comment: In ActivationService class constructor, are you initializing the activationRepo as the tutorial says?  The problem is that $this->acticationRepo in shouldSend() function is null. That is what should be fixed.

Comment: Yes, it is done exactly word for word that way.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding **use App\ActivationRepository;** in ActivationService under  **use Illuminate\Mail\Message;**

The problem seems to be that $this->activationRepo is null and not an instance of ActivationRepository;

Comment: Both ActivationRepository and ActivationService classes are under the same namespace. Adding "use ..." is not needed.

Comment: I agree with @Makan here